# What is the least hacky way to create a table with a fixed header and variable column widths?

Tags: html, css

I've scoured the internet for a way to create a table like this that doesn't feel like dark magic.

All the solutions have some convoluted way to achieve such a basic thing. They either have invisible elements, use Javascript, use divs, do just one thing etc...

What is the **simplest** way to achieve **both**?

**Edit:** By fixed header, I mean staying on top while scrolling.

Comment: Use black magic.

Comment: By “fixed header”, do you mean like the effect of `position: fixed`? Or something else?

Comment: @Ry- Yes, when you scroll, the header stays on top.

Comment: @connexo My last attempt before joining the dark side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position sticky would work.

```
th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Example found here:
https://codepen.io/WebNesting/pen/PywKEw

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky